# Debian : "pip3: command not found" after installing 'python3-pip'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, debian

I can't install pip3. I'm have error the:
`

> -bash: pip3: command not found

`
I'm made apt-get install python3-pip and python3 -m pip.

Comment: 'locate pip3' has not result

Comment: What do you need to install with `pip`? Did you install Python3 at all (apt-get install python3)?

Comment: @ sophros, Yes, i did. I want to install Flask. I'm readed in documentation, that Flask works with python3.

Comment: What does `dpkg -L python3-pip` return? Is `/usr/bin/pip3` in the list of installed files? If yes, try to call the executable by its full path: `/usr/bin/pip3 --version`, does this work?

Comment: Welcome , remove and reinstall the package `python3-pip`: `sudo apt purge python3-pip` and `sudo apt install python3-pip`.

Comment: @hoefling, the list of installed files has '/usr/bin/pip-3.2'

Comment: @GAD3R, it do not working, too